# Grub error (no such partition)

Tags: partition, grub, rescue

I'm using a dell laptop that I had dual boot on. I wanted to uninstall ubuntu and I deleted the respective partitions but when trying to reboot the computer in windows. I got this

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I've scoured everywhere and everywhere tells me that I have to find the partition with `ls` but for every partition, I get the error `Filesystem is unknown.` (Yes, I looked at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328106/grub-rescue-all-partitions-unknown-filesystem) but it hasn't been answered for 2.5 years. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196056/grub-error-unknown-filesystem-all-partitions-are-unknown?rq=1) also hasn't been answered for a really long time...)

How would I reboot back into windows?

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy solution maybe to use a live USB stick and install and run boot-repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

From here you would do the recommended repair.

This will hopefully repair grub to see windows again

Or if you don't want grub at all I would suggest that you use a windows startup repair from a live USB/disc

Comment: I installed and burned the boot-repair-disk to a live USB but it doesn't do anything when I plug it into the PC. (PC still shows error)

Comment: I also tried on my working computer (I wasn't quite sure which PC) but nothing happened either.

Comment: Could be a bad image on the USB or you need to select the boot device which can be set in BIOS. Or depending on your brand of computer can be done via one of the F{1-12} keys, google tells me for dell that key is F12. Any Debian based linux should work, if you have a known good ubuntu thumb drive that would be fine. I would first try selecting the thumb drive during start up, if it works the proceed with earlier instructions otherwise its likely a bad image and try another stick (ubuntu if you have it laying around )

Comment: Did you reboot with the LiveUSB on the PC with the grub problem? Please don't answer with Add Comment; instead, click [edit] and add your new information into the Question. As Comments pile up, old comments get pushed off screen by new comments.